# Direct Message Friend Every Day On Discord

Tags: discord, discord.js, discord.py

I'm looking to make a program that DM's my friend every day at a certain time. Is this possible? Everything I've found online is through a bot, but I just want to DM him directly through his UserID

Comment: Are you asking how to self-bot? Self-botting is against Discord ToS, so I highly disrecommend self-botting. Why not just use a bot?

Answer (score 1):

### Is it possible?

Yes, what a suprize.

### Steps

You have to do this 4 easy steps (I use [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)):

1. Create a cog
2. Create a loop
3. Check if one day is over (let's say you want to DM at 10am)
4. Send a DM
5. Start the loop

##### Step 1

First we create a cog. A cog is just a way to manage your commands, listeners etc. It's a good practice for this. Read more about here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/cogs.html?highlight=cog

```
from discord.ext import commands

class DMFriend(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(DMFriend(bot))
```

##### Step 2

To do this, we use [`tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks%20loop#discord.ext.tasks.loop). Let's say, we want to check every 10 minutes if it's 10am.

```py
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class DMFriend(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def dm_friend(self):


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(DMFriend(bot))
```

##### Step 3

We use the variable `message_sent` as a flag, that the DM doesn't get send every time it goes through. Also I do `now == 10`, because `now` should have at least one time the value `10` because it goes through (ideally) 6 times an hour.

```
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class DMFriend(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message_sent = False

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def dm_friend(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().hour
        if now == 10 and not self.message_sent:
            self.message_sent = True

        else:
            self.message_sent = False


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(DMFriend(bot))
```

##### Step 4

Now we need to send the DM. For that we use [`bot.get_user()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=bot%20get_user#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_user) and [`send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.User.send)

```
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class DMFriend(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message_sent = False
        self.user = self.bot.get_user(USER_ID)

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def dm_friend(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().hour
        if now == 10 and not self.message_sent:
            await self.user.send("Your DM")
            self.message_sent = True

        else:
            self.message_sent = False


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(DMFriend(bot))
```

##### Step 5

Now we just have to start the loop. For that we create a command.

```
import datetime
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

class DMFriend(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.message_sent = False
        self.user = self.bot.get_user(USER_ID)

    @tasks.loop(minutes=10)
    async def dm_friend(self):
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().hour
        if now == 10 and not self.message_sent:
            await self.user.send("Your DM")
            self.message_sent = True

        else:
            self.message_sent = False

    @commands.command()
    async def start(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        self.dm_friend.start()


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(DMFriend(bot))
```

**That's it!** 
**Note:** This is just an easy go-through. When the bot disconnects (crash, server restart) you'll have to start it again. Also you shouldn't mass DM users, it's against the Discord ToS.